# Making a unique index non-unique

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an already created index on a table, but I need to remove the *unique* feature.

Is there a way to make a unique index non-unique without remaking the index in Transact-SQL?

Comment: No, you will need to `DROP` the `INDEX` and recreate it. Or, you could create a second index which has the `UNIQUE` property first, and then `DROP` the old one, if you want to retain the indexing while the new one is created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last question was wrong by the way, I needed to create a non-unique index from a unique one, not the other way around. But I think the answer is right for this case too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ALTER INDEX option available to change uniqueness. You can drop and recreate the index with unique setting removed in a single statement like given below:

```sql
CREATE NonClustered INDEX Index_Name
ON  <TableName> (Column Name/s)
WITH DROP_EXISTING = ON;
```